# Coming from Trumpet: Which woodwind?

Tags: saxophone, trumpet, brass, woodwinds, clarinet

I've played trumpet for 3 years, and I'm thinking about picking up a *simple* woodwind instrument. I think personally, either clarinet or alto sax. But please, based on what I have played, price, and skill, help me find a woodwind! Thanks! :)

Comment: I  had not finished reading your post and already thought the same as you: clarinet or saxophone!

Comment: Flute: same basic construction as saxophone plus you don't need to be messing around with reeds all the time, plus it's lighter, plus it's smaller.

Answer (score 2):

Honestly, the one you like most. They all have up and down sides. Play what you like the sound and personality of the most.

Answer (score 1):

Among woodwinds, clarinet and flute have the most varied repertoire.  Much more than oboe, subcontrabassoon, ocarina, etc.  Flute embouchure may be more foreign to you than the clarinet's.
Also, as a transposing instrument, clarinets are closer to trumpets (B flat is common) than flutes (C, G).  So, clarinet.

Comment: The [subcontrabassoon](http://www.subcontrabassoon.com) doesn't even exist yet.

Comment: But it already has the beginnings of a [repertoire](https://youtu.be/XSAb232VNVA), so I stand by my statement :)

Answer (score 1):

I would say Saxophone is the easiest instrument I have learned but the hardest to get a good sound on. The fingerings are easier than clarinet and the embouchure is easier than flute. The fingerings on saxophone are very similar to recorder (and flute) so they are very easy. Just try to get lessons if you can to avoid any mistakes while learning. Also alto saxes are very cheap and you can easily switch to any other sax if you choose down the line.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, clarinet or alto sax are probably the easiest woodwinds.   But you'll be playing much the same sort of part you did on trumpet.   Flute is portable and will open up new musical horizons.   Get good and you'll be in demand too.  The world is overflowing with clarinet and sax players.

Answer (score 0):

On any, the embouchure is very different from trumpet, especially flute - which may well be the cheapest option, and smaller easier to carry, etc.

Clarinet in B♭ is a good option - same sort of range as trumpet, and uses same music, as both are transposing instruments, so you can play off your existing dots.

It's also not too different fingering wise from sax and flute, so later you can move across without too much upheaval finding notes.